# Sample .NET code for a SAML Identity Provider

Tags: .net, documentation, single-sign-on, saml

I'd like to use SAML to allow authenticated users of a website to login to other federated sites. In single sign-on parlance, that means my site needs to become an Identity Provider.

Can anyone point me to sample .NET code or documentation for implementing this?

Comment: Not really an example of code for an Identity Provider, but I suppose you found this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56640/Performing-a-SAML-Post-with-Csharp.aspx

Comment: Actually I didn't find that one. It's a good article. It demonstrates a practical way of sending a SAML response from an Identity Provider to a Service Provider. It's certainly given me some ideas.

Comment: @flipdoubt - If you add that codeproject link to your answer I'll accept it - it was exactly what I had in mind. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.componentpro.com/saml.net is a SAML Library for ASP.NET and MVC. It has very good documentation and examples to get started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ComponentSpace](http://www.componentspace.com/saml) claims to have example code for an Identity Provider and a 30-day trial, so you could at least look at the code.

Not really an example of code for an Identity Provider, but CodeProject has a good article on [Performing a SAML Post with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56640/Performing-a-SAML-Post-with-Csharp.aspx).

Comment: Their stuff looks pretty comprehensive. Well worth a look as you suggested. I think their suite is probably overkill for the little bit of functionality that I need to support. I only need to create a SAML artifact, sign it and post it to the client.

Answer (score 3):

We had really good success with the OpenSource library that [KentorIT](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) has produced.   They give you all the tools you would need to roll your own.  Including a stub identity provider that we were able to use as a test & basic auth services.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of setting up idp? I looked at the kentor idp example and it is complex and muddled with the kentor sample application.

Comment: @N-ate, do you have example?

Comment: I used Sustainsys Saml2 nuget package. If you go to their git repo they have sample projects that already work against a public IDP for testing. You can also see in the entire source code so if you wonder what some of the undocumented url are you can find them there.